# How to create a rdlc report using a stored procedure from mysql db, C#

Tags: c#, mysql, rdlc

I'm trying to create a RDLC report using a Mysql database, I got this done using a single table (with no code), but now I need to use a stored procedure to apply some parameters, how can I do this?

I have a form with a button to call the second form who has the report.

Could you bring me an example code please? I have seen some other posts but it's not clear for me

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add more information to your question, if you have some code bring to us it would be more easy to help you.

Comment: I got working a report, using a single table to fill the data set, but when i try to create a new dataset using my stored procedure (so i could apply a parameter) the SP is not shown in the available dataset list.

Then i suppose this have to be done programatically, that´s where i´m stucked.

Comment: OK you need to refresh the data, first go to the dataset and configure the datatable to have all the parameters. When the datatable/dataset in the layout has all the information required now you can go to the RDLC report and refresh the data.

Comment: look at this post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3af304ad-4396-4d01-bf16-5a77718fe869/microsoft-reporting-reportviewer-manually-creating-data-source-dynamic-assignment?forum=vbgeneral  as sql command you can use call procedure